# Jpa No entity found for query

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, sql-delete

Does anybody know why I get this error? As far as I know, the query is correct. The error reads *org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query;* even after continuously changing the code in both my Repository and Controller.

**This is the code in my Repository:**

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public void deleteById(long id) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "delete from UserModel as u where u.id=:id"
        );
        query.setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

**This is the code in my Controller:**

```
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteUser")
    public @ResponseBody
    void deleteUser(@RequestParam long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
        ResponseEntity.ok(id);
    }
```

**This is the Entity UserModel class:**

```
package nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.Models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.Views.UserViews;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserModel {

    @JsonView({UserViews.returnView.class, UserViews.returnUserView.class})
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            targetEntity = SurveyModel.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_surveys", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "survey_id")})
    public List<SurveyModel> surveyModelList;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany
    public List<QuestionModel> questionModelList;

    @Column
    public String firstname;
    @Column
    public String lastname;
    @Column
    public String username;
    @Column
    public String faculty;
    @Column
    public String email;
    @Column
    public String password;
    @Column(name = "is_admin")
    public int isAdmin = 0;
    @Column
    public int isSurvey = 0;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<SurveyModel> getSurveyModelList() {
        return surveyModelList;
    }

    public List<QuestionModel> getQuestionModelList() {
        return questionModelList;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getFaculty() {
        return faculty;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public int isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public int getIsSurvey() {
        return isSurvey;
    }

    public UserModel() {
    }

    public UserModel(String firstname, String lastname, String username, String faculty, String email, String password, int isAdmin) {
        setFirstname(firstname);
        setLastname(lastname);
        setUsername(username);
        setFaculty(faculty);
        setEmail(email);
        setPassword(password);
        setIsAdmin(isAdmin);
    }

    public UserModel(long id, String firstname, String lastname, String username, String faculty, String email, String password, int isAdmin) {
        setId(id);
        setFirstname(firstname);
        setLastname(lastname);
        setUsername(username);
        setFaculty(faculty);
        setEmail(email);
        setPassword(password);
        setIsAdmin(isAdmin);
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setSurveyModelList(List<SurveyModel> surveyModelList) {
        this.surveyModelList = surveyModelList;
    }

    public void setQuestionModelList(List<QuestionModel> questionModelList) {
        this.questionModelList = questionModelList;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setFaculty(String faculty) {
        this.faculty = faculty;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setAdmin(int isAdmin) {
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    public void setIsAdmin(int isAdmin) {
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    public void setIsSurvey(int isSurvey) {
        this.isSurvey = isSurvey;
    }
}
```

**This is the stacktrace:**

```
2022-06-13 19:06:34.136  INFO 18684 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@58ce9668 testClass = TestUserRepository, testInstance = nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.TestUserRepository@7957aa57, testMethod = testRemoveUser@TestUserRepository, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@172b013 testClass = TestUserRepository, locations = '{}', classes = '{class nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.EwaBackendApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@272ed83b, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@625732, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@247d8ae, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@932bc4a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4d5b6aac, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@79b4d0f], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@6c4786af]; rollback [true]
2022-06-13 19:06:34.969  INFO 18684 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@58ce9668 testClass = TestUserRepository, testInstance = nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.TestUserRepository@7957aa57, testMethod = testRemoveUser@TestUserRepository, testException = org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query; nested exception is javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query, mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@172b013 testClass = TestUserRepository, locations = '{}', classes = '{class nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.EwaBackendApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@272ed83b, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@625732, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@247d8ae, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@932bc4a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4d5b6aac, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@79b4d0f], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.populatedRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.resetRequestContextHolder' -> true, 'org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false]]
2022-06-13 19:06:34.978  INFO 18684 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-06-13 19:06:34.983  INFO 18684 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-06-13 19:06:35.006  INFO 18684 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query; nested exception is javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:382)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.Repositories.UserRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa98cd13.findById(<generated>)
    at nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.TestUserRepository.testRemoveUser(TestUserRepository.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1667)
    at nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.Repositories.UserRepository.findById(UserRepository.java:55)
    at nl.hva.soufian.EWABackend.Repositories.UserRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dada401a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 77 more
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: Why are you calling [`getSingleResult()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult())?

Comment: Can you post your @Entity UserModel class ? If you don't have it, then that's the problem.

Comment: @tgdavies I have added the complete stack trace of the exception. The reason I am calling getSingleResult() as this method is only supposed to delete one Object by Id, it can't delete multiple Objects at once and that's why I'm not using a getResultList()

Comment: @NiceBooks I added the Entity UserModel Class, it should be visible now

Comment: Read the Javadoc for `getSingleResult`. It expects the query to be a select. Your delete query is never going to return anything.

Comment: @tgdavies oooh thanks, so I should remove it and then it should work?

Comment: I don't know. Your code may have other problems too.

Comment: Does your @Repository class implement CrudRepository<UserModel,Long> ? In that case, you need not implement deleteById(long) as it is already implemented for you.

Comment: @NiceBooks no, my class implements some methods from an interface I created, one of the methods is DeleteById()

Comment: Well, the Spring way of doing it is by inheriting from CrudRepository<Entity, ID>.